# python: error when executing subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

when I execute the following function in centos, I get the error

```
def install_requests_lib():
   try:
      import requests
      return
   except ImportError, e:
      print "module does not exist, installing..."
      if(platform.system().lower()=='darwin'):
          print "install requests before proceeding, run **sudo pip install requests**"
          sys.exit(2)
      elif(platform.system().lower()=='linux'):
          print "installing"
          p=Popen(["yum","-y","install","python-requests"], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
          p.communicate()
          print p.returncode
```

error:

```
module does not exist, installing...
installing
You need to give some command
1
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I executed with `stdin=PIPE` argument, still I get the same error.

Comment: Does your script have permissions to do `yum install`? You can also redirect stderr to stdout to see all output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments in your arg list after `"yum"` aren't being executed if you give the argument `shell=True`.  Remove the `shell=True` argument and it should work.

Alternatively, you could supply the full command line as a string and keep the `shell=True` argument:

```
p=Popen("yum install -y python-requests", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

but it's generally discouraged to do so, [for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/7007605).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute `yum -y install`, when you mean `yum install -y`.